# Compiz plugins / filter - ordering

Tags: 14.04, compiz, plugins, colors, color-management

Using Ubuntu 14.04. In Compiz, I have enabled `Negative` and `OBS` plugins (color filters). What I want is, filter A should be applied after filter B (I want to be able to control the order). How can I achieve that?

Note: In particular, I want the `Negative` filter to be applied before `OBS` settings. To see why this is needed. Suppose I want 70% brightness (in OBS) and I want to invert the colors (prefer white on black). What I want is:

```
Original:  Black on White (#000 on #FFF)
After Negative:  #FFF on #000
After OBS (final):  #AAA on #000 (approx).
```

What is happening is, OBS is applied first, resulting in:

```
After OBS:  #000 on #AAA
After Negative (final):  #FFF on #444 (approx).
```

Resulting in overall more brightness than I want and increased glare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have good question. And i confirm that i have same behaviour of Neg and OBS on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Unfortunately, Compiz developement for Ubuntu stops after 10.04 LTS, so no any bug reports or feature requests about Compiz going to be solved anymore. Even worse, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS are lack of Compiz Color Filter, which will solve your task with ease (and a lot more).

So currently there is no direct solution for you. But there is two more or less useful workarounds.

1. Use any black window or picture as background, and from OBS, use Opacity instead of Brightness, on your target window. I use it and it work well, but weird when many windows opened.
2. There is a way exist to modify Neg filter so it can dim the window, but only by a fixed amount...

A system without CCF is not useable for me. So i take some developement [1]. Finally i found a nice way to emulate CCF using Neg. And also, long lasting error with incorrect color inversion (Windows(R)-like inversion or simple RGB-inversion) was fixed by me. How to obtain it:

*WARNING, not for production machines. Try first on test machine!*

Check you have correct version, both outputs should match:

```
$ compiz --version
Compiz 0.9.11.3

$ dd if=/usr/lib/compiz/libneg.so bs=1 skip=46052 count=505

void neg_fragment () {                                   
    vec3 color = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) - gl_FragColor.rgb; 
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, gl_FragColor.a);          
}                                                        
 18PluginClassHandlerI9NegWindow10CompWindowLi0EE18PluginClassHandlerI9NegScreen10CompScreenLi0EEN10CompAction9ContainerE9NegScreen9NegWindowN10CompPlugin24VTableForScreenAndWindowI9NegScreen9NegWindowLi0EEE15NegPluginVTable
505+0 records in
505+0 records out
```

Create file *neg-patch*. Note, '1.0' is brightness you need:

```
void neg_fragment(){;
float l,d,i,a;
vec3 t;
i=gl_FragColor.r;
i=min(i,gl_FragColor.g);
i=min(i,gl_FragColor.b);
a=gl_FragColor.r;
a=max(a,gl_FragColor.g);
a=max(a,gl_FragColor.b);
l=i+a;
d=1.0-l;
t=vec3(gl_FragColor.r+d,gl_FragColor.g+d,gl_FragColor.b+d)*1.0;
gl_FragColor=vec4(t,gl_FragColor.a);
}
```

Backup:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/compiz/libneg.so /usr/lib/compiz/libneg.so.bk
```

Patch:

```
printf '\0\0' >> neg-patch; cat neg-patch | sudo dd of=/usr/lib/compiz/libneg.so bs=1 seek=46052 conv=notrunc
```

And check:

```
$ dd if=/usr/lib/compiz/libneg.so bs=1 skip=46052 count=505
```

Restart and viola, it should work. Sometimes it even takes to work immediately. We build our own CCF filter!

And it all shows that all functionality need to implement CCF is exist inside current Compiz. So there is no real reason to remove so useful CCF from Ububtu's Compiz, except lazyness?

This solution is also compatible with melatonine/cold/warm color effects as described in lian1238's posts in [1]. Note you should never exceed 500 bytes size of your *neg-patch* file!

Hope it helps.

-jpka

[1] http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1419702